# gnome's file v3.6.2 (nautilus) has lost the inline folder expand function

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I just update to current gnome 3.6. So this will also bring an redesigned file app (nautilus). In the ListView I miss the folder expand Icon to expand the folder inline.
With double click of course a new will be opened.

Has anyone an Idea how to activate the inline expand feature?
Maybe it's lost in the redesign.

[image: BSP Image]

Comment: There seems to be no coverage at all on this. It's not even mentioned on https://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Roadmap/3.6 . And it is upsetting me more than that split view is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make clear what this is about: It is officially called "tree view" ([screenshot](http://uwstopia.nl/blog/2005/07/improving-nautilus))

This feature has been removed in Gnome 3.6 .

[A poll on omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/is-the-new-nautilus-a-step-in-the-direction-poll) mentions it, linking to the [git commit](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=ef467c8775392d0f0feb0e38f7a80f2d41719d84).

More to the point is the last comment in this [gnome bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444667):

> William Jon McCann [developer] 2012-08-14 21:43:49 UTC
>
> The tree view has been removed from nautilus.

Sad.

Comment: That's it and I also found why it's removed. _It is the list view after all. Tree models don't work well on touch and it isn't consistent with the file chooser._ (http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=ef467c8775392d0f0feb0e38f7a80f2d41719d84) This is rubbish !!! What about the power user. I don't use "finger pointing"

Comment: Note that, in Gnome 3.8, THE TREE VIEW IS BACK!!!
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-February/msg03327.html

Comment: It's really crazy and upsetting they change such important daily feature just like that ...
Thanks for sharing ! How to get that on my Ubuntu 13.04 ?!

Comment: This is insanity.

Comment: Stephane: add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 ; apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 11):

Tree view is actually available in 13.10, 14.04 beta: Under preferences, check this option:

[image: Check Navigate folder in a tree, under Display tab.]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the TreeView in the left pane, then it was removed.

Check for more changes: http://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2012/08/30/on-nautilus/

Comment: Thanks, But no, I mean the expand in the main window. There has been a small triangle direct in front of the folders. So you could expand the folder without getting a complete new view.